# Right align not showing correct data in table cell in case of data overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML table with all column right aligned and `overflow:hidden` is set for all table cells. When I get data like "abcde12345", as right align is set, it should display "12345" only(assuming column width can display only 5 characters)  and "abcde" should get truncated.

But its showing "abcde" only whether table cells are left justified or right justified. As it is right justified in case of data overflow I want to display last characters.

Is it limitation of HTML? Or any suggestion how can I achieve that?

Here is sample code:

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

<div style="overflow:hidden; width: 150px;">
 <table border="3" style="table-layout : fixed; width: 150px;">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="overflow:hidden;text-align: right;">Jan</td>
    <td style="overflow:hidden;text-align: right;">$abcde123456789</td>
  </tr>
 </table> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add -

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

```css
td {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow:hidden; width: 150px;">
 <table border="3" style="table-layout : fixed; width: 150px;">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="overflow:hidden;text-align: right;">Jan</td>
    <td style="overflow:hidden;text-align: right;">$abcde123456789</td>
  </tr>
 </table> 
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't work. "word-wrap: break-word;" is displaying all data not truncating anything. I want data to be truncated in overflow but display last characters.